# IntelliJ: Refactor signature to use parameters properties

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible in IntelliJ to do this kind of refactoring

```
public class Demo {

    public long sum(Model model) {
        int a = model.getA();
        int b = model.getB();
        System.out.println(model.getA());
        System.out.println(model.getB());
        return (long) a + b;
    }

    //refactor to

    public long sum(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        return (long) a + b;
    }

    private static class Model {
        private int a;
        private int b;
        private int c;

        //getter & boilerplate
    }
}
```

would be quite nice IMHO to reduce complexity in certain cases.

Googled around for a while and tried various refactoring dialogues- couldn't find anything better than "Change Signature" yet.

**EDIT:** refined Example to have multiple usages per parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question!
Yes, this is possible using the combination of `Extract parameter` and `Inline variable`.

1. Starting point
   [image]
2. Over `getA()`, `right click > Refactor > Extract > Parameter` (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> on Windows).
   The result is
   [image]

   Do the same with `getB()`.
3. Invoke the *Inline variable* quick-fix/refactoring on the local variables (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> on Windows)
   [image]
4. Admire the result and rename accordingly
   [image]

---

I can do all of that in a matter of 5 seconds using shortcuts and quick-fixes navigation ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! While 'Extract Variable' offers to replace multiple occurrences, this seems not to be the case for 'Extract Parameter'.. still curious if there is any even faster alternative ;)

Comment: @FranzEbner unfortunately there is no alternative as of now. You can still open a feature request on Youtrack, I'll upvote.

Comment: @FranzEbner btw, even with multiple usages this works fine

Comment: really seems to be the single best option currently, thanks for the feature request